# A saved program gives different output than writing it in the command line in Octave

Tags: octave

New to Octave.  When I enter a simple script in the command line line by line I get a different output than the same program in a saved file.

I've googled, checked for answers on stackoverflow, checked documentation, and the wiki for Octave.

```
sum=0
for x = 1:10
  sum = sum + 1
  disp(x);
endfor
```

Those five lines are it.  When I enter them line by line in the command window, output is:
sum =  1
 1
sum =  2
 2
sum =  3
 3
sum =  4
 4
sum =  5
 5
sum =  6
 6
sum =  7
 7
sum =  8
 8
sum =  9
 9
sum =  10
 10

But when I save and run in the editor, I just get this:

```
sum =  10
```

Comment: Just a wild guess: is JIT enabled? And please add GNU Octave Version and used OS

Comment: Windows, version 5.1.0.

I don't know about JIT.  I looked it up and didn't fully understand it.  I didn't change any settings though and only downloaded this about a week ago.

Comment: I am unable to recreate this issue. I get the same results whether the script is entered line by line at the command prompt or run from a m file.  Some problems I've had loek this are because I've unexpectedly changed a variable between runs, or didn't clear variables.   Also, people often use variable names that overlap function names (like you did for sum) which can sometimes cause repeatability concerns.

Comment: That was it nick!  I named the program the same thing as the variable!  Still odd that that should affect 'save and run', but I changed the program name and no prob.  Thanks.